# Android sdk manager disapear quickly in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

when I click on Android sdk manager button,

[image]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://cld.persiangig.com/preview/YbEiUKc9JS/123.png))</sub>

The Android sdk manager window doesn't open! Just I see this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [persiangig.com](http://cld.persiangig.com/preview/yXzDMZcL3h/321.png))</sub>

And then nothing else! I can't see the packages that installed or not...

In console appear:

```
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Access is denied.
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3550 or swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:402)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:376)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
[2014-10-07 22:42:24 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

what should I've done?
Help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it via the .exe file in the SDK Tools install folder instead of through Eclipse. Eclipse has so many little bugs like that I have made it a habit to do as much as possible without using Eclipse to do it ha.